# Below Excel VBA function is only working for first IF condition, ELSEIF is not working

Tags: excel, vba

Below Excel VBA function is only working for first `If` condition, `ElseIf` is not working.

```vb
Function Alarms(L2) As String
    Set a = Application.WorksheetFunction

    If IsError(a.Find("HHH", L2, 1)) = False Then 
        Alarms = "HHH HTRP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find(" HI", L2, 1)) <> True Then   
        Alarms = "HI"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("IOP", L2, 1)) = False Then   
        Alarms = "IOP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("OOP", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "OOP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("ANS", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "ANS"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find(" HH", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "HH"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("HTRP", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "HHH HTRP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find(" LO", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "LO"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find(" LL", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "LL"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("LLL", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "LLL LTRP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("LTRP", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "LLL LTRP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("NR", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "NR"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("DV", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "DV"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("VEL", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "VEL"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("TRIP", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "TRIP"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("MHI", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "MHI MLO"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("MLO", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "MHI MLO"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("CERR", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "CERR"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("PERR", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "PERR"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("OVR", L2, 1)) = False Then   
        Alarms = "OVR"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("FAULT", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "FAULT"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("INT", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "INT"
    ElseIf IsError(a.Find("ALM", L2, 1)) = False Then    
        Alarms = "ANN"
    Else
        Alarms = "-"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Don't use `WorksheetFunction`... Use [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) and test if the result is `> 0`. Also, it always helps to create a [reprex].

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using a long chain of `If...ElseIf...` statements that differ only in one of the parameters, there's almost always a better way of doing it. You could iterate over an array of those strings, for example.

Comment: Is this a UDF? If yes, I am guessing calling `WorksheetFunction.Find()` is disallowed in UDFs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Case would do the trick:

```
Public Function Alarms(Target As Range) As String

    Select Case True
        Case InStr(Target.Value, "HHH") > 0, InStr(Target.Value, "HTRP") > 0 '<Note: both values checked here.
            Alarms = "HHH HTRP"
        Case InStr(Target.Value, " HI") > 0
            Alarms = "HI"
        Case InStr(Target.Value, "IOP") > 0
            Alarms = "IOP"
        Case InStr(Target.Value, "OOP") > 0
            Alarms = "OOP"
        Case InStr(Target.Value, "ANS") > 0
            Alarms = "ANS"
        Case InStr(Target.Value, " HH") > 0
            Alarms = "HH"
        Case Else
            Alarms = "-"
    End Select

End Function
```

Note - "OOP" is different from "oop"